# Q.all running before forEach

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, q

I am trying to make a promise function that reads an array of e-mails, then find the user ID and push it to another array.

The problem is that my `Q.all` function is running before `_.forEach` is done. Check it out:

```
var deferred = Q.defer(),
    promises = [],
    _ = require('lodash');

_.forEach(users, function(user) {
    User.findOne({
      username: user
    }, function(err, member) {
      if (err)
        console.log(err);

      var memberId = member._id;
      promises.push(members.push(memberId));
    });
});

Q.all(promises)
  .then(function(promises) {
    deferred.resolve(promises);
    console.log(promises); // This always returns -> []
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
  });

return deferred.promise;
```

So everytime I try to `console.log` my array of promises, I get an empty array. I even tried to use JavaScript native `forEach` function, but it did not work.

Is `forEach` the problem or `Q.all` is not the appropriate function for this case?

Thanks in advance.

---

**SOLVED** (Solution suggested by **Robert Moskal**)

In my case, the `async` library along with `Q.defer()` solved the problem.

```
var async = require('async'),
    deferred = Q.defer();

async.map(users, function(each, done){
  User.findOne({
    username: each
  }, function(err, member) {
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
        done(null, member._id);
      });
  }, function(err, results){
    if (err)
      deferred.reject(err);
    deferred.resolve(results);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the User.findOne function is asynchronous, so the Q.all function gets executed before anything gets pushed on the promise array.

It's usually better not to mix callbacks and promises. As for fixing it.  If that's a mongoose model, then you could use the promise based version of findOne:

```
var deferred = Q.defer(),
    promises = [],
    _ = require('lodash');

_.forEach(users, function(user) {
    promises.push(User.findOne({
      username: user}));
});

Q.all(promises)
  .then(function(promises) {
    deferred.resolve(promises);
    console.log(promises); // This always returns -> []
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
  });

return deferred.promise;
```

Or you could use the async library which might look something like this:

```
async.map(users, function(each, done){

 User.findOne({
      username: user
    }, function(err, member) {
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
        done(null, member._id); 

    });
},
function(err, results){
  //results holds your array of ids
    }
);
```